# Windows8 Getting Error "Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete." on touch of Custom Control Date Picker

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have created a custom control for date picker n Wndows8 App using C# and Xaml. When I am using my mouse to expand comboBox for date or Month or Year its working fine when I am using touch screen and clicking the control then its crash all the time giving me "Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete." Error. What should I do to remove this error?
Code for custom control:

XAML Code:

```
 <UserControl
    x:Class="Win8.MainApp.User_Control.DatePicker"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Win8.MainApp.User_Control"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DateTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontWeight="Light" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <!--<ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding}" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid Width="370">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DateTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Date.Day}"  Width="100" Height="30" MaxDropDownHeight="1" SelectedItem="{Binding Day, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <ComboBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="20,0,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DateTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Date.Month}"  Width="100" Height="30" MaxDropDownHeight="1" SelectedItem="{Binding Month, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <ComboBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="20,0,0,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DateTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Date.Year}"  Width="120" Height="30" MaxDropDownHeight="1" SelectedItem="{Binding Year, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

.Cs Code

```
 public sealed partial class DatePicker : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _day;
    private int _month;
    private int _year;
    private Date _date = new Date();

    public int Day
    {
        get { return _day; }
        set
        {
            if (_day == value) return;
            _day = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Day");
        }
    }

    public int Month
    {
        get { return _month; }
        set
        {
            if (_month == value) return;
            _month = value;
            _date.Day =
                new ObservableCollection<int>((Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, _month))));
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Month");
        }
    }

    public int Year
    {
        get { return _year; }
        set
        {
            if (_year == value) return;
            _year = value;
            _date.Day = new ObservableCollection<int>((Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(_year, _month))));
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Year");
        }
    }

    public Date Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
    }

    private int GetDaysInMonth(int year, int month)
    {
        return DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
    }

    public DatePicker()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SetTodaysDate();
        SetDataSource();
    }

    private void SetTodaysDate()
    {
        Day = DateTime.Now.Day;
        Month = DateTime.Now.Month;
        Year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    }

    private void SetDataSource()
    {
        int year = DateTime.Now.Year - 10;
        _date.Day = new ObservableCollection<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, GetDaysInMonth(Year, Month)));
        _date.Month = new ObservableCollection<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 12));
        _date.Year = new ObservableCollection<int>(Enumerable.Range(year, 20));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}

public class Date : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<int> _day;
    private ObservableCollection<int> _month;
    private ObservableCollection<int> _year;

    public ObservableCollection<int> Day
    {
        get { return _day; }
        set
        {
            if (_day == value) return;
            _day = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Day");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<int> Month
    {
        get { return _month; }
        set
        {
            if (_month == value) return;
            _month = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Month");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<int> Year
    {
        get { return _year; }
        set
        {
            if (_year == value) return;
            _year = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Year");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND!

I had the exact same problem on WinRT and found how to solve it: need to remove the "MaxDropDownHeight" property. As soon this property is assigned, no matter the value, it will cause this problem on touch devices.

Try remove it in your code too :-).